# No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite on app image

Tags: java, sqlite, maven, javafx

I have a JavaFX app that connects to SQLite using

```java
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:data.sqlite");
```

I have the dependency for SQLite driver on my pom file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.32.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I can run the App smoothly using Maven Goals `javafx:compile` and `javafx:run`, everything works as expected and the app has no trouble querying the db. The `data.sqlite` file is created on the project's root folder (same folder as `src/` and `pom.xml`).

However, when I try to run an executable file built with `jlink`, I get the error described on the thread's title. First, I ran maven goal `javafx:jlink`. This generates some stuff at `target/image/`. I navigated to `target/image/bin` and ran `./java -m <name-of-my-module>/<group-id>.App`, which is the command for running the file I built. Then I get:

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:data.sqlite
```

And a `NullPointerException` because of the database init routines that try to access my database connection. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: It seems that the solution has something to do with adding a `Class.forName()` statement before calling `DriverManager.getConnection()`. I tried doing the following:

```java
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:data.sqlite");
```

By doing that, now the app renders! However, it still crashes. I get `ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC`. Any hints...?

Comment: With "modern" (Java 6+?) JDBC drivers, Class.forName should not be needed anymore

Comment: Can you check if sqlite-jdbc is part of the generated runtime image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fear this will not work directly with jlink because as far as I have seen SQLite is not yet modularized. I have described an alternative approach here https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX which also uses jlink internally but only to create a dedicated runtime. With this approach linking SQLite works. I know that because my own applications also use the exact same version of the SQLite driver without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using Draque Thompson's [Module Info Inject](https://github.com/DraqueT/Module-Info-Inject). Basically what the program does is creating a `module-info.class` for your `.jar`, letting JLink see it as a module. (Sorry if the explanation is lacking, I don't have deep knowledge of Java's module system).

So basically what I done was:

1. Clone Module-Info-Inject and run it.
2. Select the desired jar folder and click "Inject".
3. On the generated `module-info.class` file, get the module's name. In my case it was `sqlite.jdbc`.
4. Add the new module to my project's `module-info.java`.

The generated `module-info.class` file for SQLite driver:

```java
module sqlite.jdbc {
    requires transitive java.logging;
    requires transitive java.sql;

    exports org.sqlite;
    exports org.sqlite.core;
    exports org.sqlite.date;
    exports org.sqlite.javax;
    exports org.sqlite.jdbc3;
    exports org.sqlite.jdbc4;
    exports org.sqlite.util;

    provides java.sql.Driver with org.sqlite.JDBC;
}
```

Requiring the module in my project's `module-info.java`:

```java
module com.demo {
    requires sqlite.jdbc;

    / * ... * /

    exports pkg.app;
}
```

Comment: I am glad you were able to solve your problem but in the general case just adding a missing module-info.class is not enough. That way you are not able to solve, e.g., split package issues and other such stuff.